# Getting the RSS feed for Wikipedia articles I've created

Tags: rss, feeds, mediawiki, wikipedia

Is it possible to get a RSS feed for the **new** articles I've created on [Wikipedia?](http://en.wikipedia.org/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the feed if you check out the [New pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aNewPages) watch and filter for your name only.

1. Toolbox > Special Pages > Recent changes and logs > New pages
2. Enter your Wikipedia handle in the **Username:** field
3. Hit **Go**

You'll then get results showing all the newly created pages started by that username.

Grab the "Special:New pages" Atom feed that is created for that result output.

The URL for that will look like this:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:NewPages&feed=atom&hideliu=&hidepatrolled=&hidebots=&hideredirs=1&limit=50&namespace=0&username=USERNAME
```

Replace USERNAME in the above with yours.