# Special/New pages. I cannot see my uploads

Tags: rss, wikipedia, mediawiki, wikimedia-commons

I've tried to apply this recipe: [Getting the RSS feed for Wikipedia articles I've created](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/12994/getting-the-rss-feed-for-wikipedia-articles-ive-created) to see the files I've uploaded recently on Commons (e.g: [this file](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:T%C3%AAte_de_femme_coiff%C3%A9e_de_corne_de_b%C3%A9lier.jpg) ). But I cannot see any log in:

```
http://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3ANewPages&namespace=all&tagfilter=&username=Plindenbaum
```

It says:

> There are no results for this report.

(I tried this the day I've uploaded my pictures).

Is it me or is it a bug from Wikipedia?

Comment: If you just want a graphical list of your uploads, that's what Special:AllMyUploads is for (it's also linked inthe personal toolbar, top right). https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:AllMyUploads

Answer (score 2):

You're requesting NewPages, but an upload may not be counted as a page..

How about this - http://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=feedcontributions&user=Plindenbaum&feedformat=atom ?

Answer (score 0):

Special:NewPages does not show all new pages, but only the recent ones.

Right now, the [earliest thing you can see](http://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3aNewPages&dir=prev&limit=500&namespace=all) is from  9 January 2012.

[Your file](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3aT%C3%AAte_de_femme_coiff%C3%A9e_de_corne_de_b%C3%A9lier.jpg) has been uploaded on 4 September 2011‎, so no wonder it is not shown in New Pages.

Use eug's trick to get the list you want. You can use the Atom protocol to get more or less results, or get earlier results. Use a RSS reader or write your own HTTP requests.